# How to change the pen color in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to create a software that works like a sketchpad. One of the capabilities is for the user to be able to change the pen colour. I have no idea how to do so. How can the user change the pen colour?

Comment: The options when drawing objects are well documented, including those for specifying which color to use when doing the drawing. Have you read any documentation before asking this question?

Comment: What do you mean by pen?

Comment: If you have another question please _ask_ another question with regard to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You can't keep updating same question with new questions.

Comment: you will have to use [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) and `create_oval()` to create every dot separatelly in some (random) distance from mouse position.

Comment: @furas rolled-back this to its initial question, making this comment unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Turtle, which is literally made for drawing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter` doesn't have "pens"—so the whole concept does not apply. It *does* have something called a `Canvas` which defines a container object that can display stuff added ("drawn") on it (such as arcs, lines, textm etc). Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html) about it. A `Canvas` instance contains other sub-objects to represent these sub-objects and each one of them has its own independent set of attributes that define things like its color, width, etc as applicable.

For example a `Canvas` [line](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_line.html) objects has a bunch of different ones which can be specified when instances of one are created. Here's a [list of them](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_line.html). After a canvas object is created, some or all of its attributes can be changed by calling the universal [`configure()` method](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) on it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to constantly create a tiny line wherever the mouse cursor is. Variables record where the cursor is, and when it is held down it draws. Here is an example of what you are trying to do (Python 3):
https://gist.github.com/nikhilkumarsingh/85501ee2c3d8c0cfa9d1a27be5781f06